# rename hasOwnProperty but prevent enumeration

Tags: javascript, enumeration, prototype-programming

I'm having to use hasOwnProperty a lot in my code and it is annoyingly long and camel-cased to type. I wanted to be able to just say `myObj.has('x')`, but when I tried to make an alias for hOP in the Object.prototype 'has' now gets enumerated in for..in loops. What is the best way to get what I want? I mean I could just make a global function that works like `has(obj, prop)` but I like the dot format better and I would like to know what tricks javascript might have up it's sleeve, so I am looking for suggestions.

**Update:** this seems pretty hacky but is `String.prototype.in = function(obj){return obj.hasOwnProperty(this)}` OK? With that I can then say `if ( 'x'.in(myObj) ) {...` Unfortunately it adds another layer of function call rather than just aliasing hasOwnProperty, but I like the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only prevent enumeration in ES5 compatible browsers, using `Object.defineProperty()`:

```
Object.defineProperty(myObj, "has", { value: Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty });
```

`defineProperty()` defaults to setting non-enumerable properties.  A better ES3 approach would be to just alias the function and don't stick it on `Object.prototype`:

```
var has = function (ob, prop) { 
    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(ob, prop); 
}
```

I don't see anything wrong with your own `String.prototype.in` approach either, except maybe potential naming collisions in the future, but that's your call.  Calling it `String.prototype.on` would remove ambiguity with the `in` operator.

Comment: Thank. I tried using defineProperty before but I guess I was using it wrong

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
Object.prototype.has = function(x) {
  return this.hasOwnProperty(x)
}
```

Take care when using SomeNativeThing.prototype and use

```
if ((typeof Object.prototype.has) !== 'function') {
   ...
}
```

to ensure your not overriding anything

as @pomeh states, using `Object.prototype.has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` is way better

Comment: why not `Object.prototype.has = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;` ?

Comment: sidenote: don't extend Object.prototype. extend myObject.prototype instead

Comment: Uh, you are ignoring the important half of my question "...but prevent enumeration". I already tried pomeh's way but then I get errors in my for..in loops because "has" shows up on every basic object as enumerable.